# how to check a matrix value by value if the number is 1

Tags: python, matrix

I want to check all the values in a matrix and if it's 1 print the x,y coordinates.

This is my matrix:

```
0, 0, 0, 1,
1, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 1, 0, 0,
```

This is my code so far:

```
m = open('matrix.txt', 'r')
l = []
l = [line.split() for line in m]
for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        p = int(l[x][y][:-1])
        if p == 1:
            print(x, y)
```

But when i run it i get this:

the coordinates:

```
0 3
1 0
2 2
3 1
```

and then this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over `range(10)` while you have a 4x4 matrix. You need `range(4)` instead.

But this is not the pythonic way to go with this task.First of all you don't need to initial a list when you want to use a list comprehension so you don't need `l=[]` at all,then as a pythonic way for dealing with files you can use [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) that close the file after the nested block of code.And for iterating over an iterable and getting the indices you can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

```
with open('matrix.txt', 'r') as f:
    li = [line.split() for line in f]

    for index,row in enumerate(li):
       for i,item in enumerate(row):
        if item == '1':
            print(index,i)
```

Also note that in your code the line `p = int(l[x][y][:-1])` is redundant and you don't need to convert the item to integer you can simply check with `'1'`.

Comment: And the Pythonic way to walk through a matrix is `for x, y in itertools.product(range(4), repeat=2):...`

Comment: @EliKorvigo Yep, but in this case we just have 2 loop and it make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import product
```

You can do it simply this way

```
with open('matrix.txt', 'r') as m:
    l = [line.split() for line in m]
    result = [ (x,y)  for x,y in list(product(range(4), range(4))) if int(l[x][y][:-1]) ]

print result

[(0, 3), (1, 0), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

I kept the same splitting line as yours,
Then in the second one I iterate over all the combinations and keep only x,y when 1 is met.
And you get the expected result

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively I will suggest using `numpy` to deal with matrix.

Here is how to do it with `argwhere`:

```
In [6]: import numpy as np

In [7]: m = np.matrix([
[0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0]])

# use argwhere to find the coordinates
In [8]: np.argwhere(m == 1)
Out[8]:
array([[[0, 3]],

       [[1, 0]],

       [[2, 2]],

       [[3, 1]]])
```

To return as a list of tuples:

```
In [10]: list(map(tuple, np.argwhere(m == 1)))
Out[10]: [(0, 3), (1, 0), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

To construct your matrix, you can do it with:

```
m = np.matrix([map(int, filter(lambda x: x, line.strip().split(","))) 
               for line in f]) # where f is your opened file
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the matrix from the file:

```
with open('matrix.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines=[line.split() for line in f.readlines()]
```

You can find all the 1 indices with one line:

```
indices=[[(i,j) for i,a in enumerate(line) if a==1] for j,line in enumerate(lines)]
```

And if you want to flatten the array:

```
indices=reduce(list.__add__,indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another pythonic way would be to read a comma-separated data file with the `csv` library and `enumerate()` over rows and column fields:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

mtx = csv.reader(open("matrix.txt", "rb"))
for row_idx, row_data in enumerate(mtx):
    for cell_enum in [(col_idx, col_val.strip()) for col_idx, col_val in enumerate(row_data)]:
        if cell_enum[1] == '1':
            print row_idx, cell_enum[0]
```

Output:

```
0 3
1 0
2 2
3 1
```

**Edit**: Removed `int()` cast so that the `try..except` block is no longer necessary.

Comment: it throws a SintaxError for the`,` in  `except ValueError, ve:` is there another way to except the `ValueError` and the `ve`?